# How to automatically press the Tab key to execute minibuffer-complete after executing imenu?

Tags: completion, minibuffer, imenu

I first set up this key binding :
`(global-set-key (kbd "<f4>") (lambda () (interactive) (other-window -1)))`

When I use imenu I always have to perform the following steps:

Step 1: Press `M-x`
Step 2: type `imenu` , Press `RET`
Step 3: Press `TAB` ;; run `minibuffer-complete`
Step 4: Press `f4` ;; run `(other-window -1)` for switch to `*Completions*` buffer
Step 5: Press `C-s` ;; run `isearch-forward`

I want to use a function to perform the above 5 steps.

Is this possible?
This is useful when there are a lot of functions. [image: Final Results]

Similarly, if want to display struct, need to insert between the second and third steps:
Step 3: type `Class` , Press `RET`

My current solution is to use xdotool:

show struct list: `(global-set-key (kbd "<f8>") (lambda () (interactive) (shell-command "xdotool key alt+x && xdotool type 'imenu' && xdotool key Return && xdotool type 'Class' && xdotool key Return && xdotool key Tab && xdotool key F4 && xdotool key ctrl+s")))`

show function list: `(global-set-key (kbd "<f9>") (lambda () (interactive) (shell-command "xdotool key alt+x && xdotool type 'imenu' && xdotool key Return && xdotool key Tab && xdotool key F4 && xdotool key ctrl+s")))`

I want to quickly locate the item by fuzzy search in `*Completions*` buffer,  Instead of pressing Tab key complete in the minibuffer

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but maybe this will help:

```lisp
(defun foo ()
  "..."
  (interactive)
  (minibuffer-with-setup-hook #'minibuffer-complete
    (call-interactively #'imenu)))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f4>") 'foo)
```

Comment: This is very useful for me, but can only complete the first 3 steps.